# Vagrant mount failing on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, mount, vagrant

I'm trying to do a `vagrant up` on a new project and the mounting of the folder seems to fail.
I already tried to us the VBoxGuestAddition hack but it's not cutting it.

Vagrant 1.8.1
Virtualbox 5.0
Host: Windows 10

Output of the console:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'debian/jessie64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'debian/jessie64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: project_default_1464776375177_93370
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
No installation found.
stdin: is not a tty
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp cpp-4.8 cpp-4.9 fakeroot gcc gcc-4.8 gcc-4.9 libasan0 libasan1
  libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libcloog-isl4 libfakeroot
  libgcc-4.8-dev libgcc-4.9-dev libgomp1 libisl10 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3
  libmpfr4 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86
  linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.16
  linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-4.8-locales gcc-4.9-locales gcc-multilib autoconf
  automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc
  libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg
  libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg gcc-4.9-multilib gcc-4.9-doc libasan1-dbg
  liblsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg glibc-doc make-doc
Recommended packages:
  linux-image
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp cpp-4.8 cpp-4.9 dkms fakeroot gcc gcc-4.8 gcc-4.9 libasan0
  libasan1 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libcloog-isl4
  libfakeroot libgcc-4.8-dev libgcc-4.9-dev libgomp1 libisl10 libitm1 liblsan0
  libmpc3 libmpfr4 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86
  linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common
  linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.16 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 36 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 153 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libasan0 amd64 4.8.4-1 [63.3 kB]
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libatomic1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [8,992 B]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libasan1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [195 kB]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libcilkrts5 amd64 4.9.2-10 [40.1 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libisl10 amd64 0.12.2-2 [440 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libcloog-isl4 amd64 0.18.2-1+b2 [61.8 kB]
Get:7 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgomp1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [37.8 kB]
Get:8 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libitm1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [29.2 kB]
Get:9 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main liblsan0 amd64 4.9.2-10 [92.8 kB]
Get:10 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libmpfr4 amd64 3.1.2-2 [527 kB]
Get:11 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libquadmath0 amd64 4.9.2-10 [129 kB]
Get:12 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libtsan0 amd64 4.9.2-10 [212 kB]
Get:13 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libubsan0 amd64 4.9.2-10 [82.4 kB]
Get:14 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libmpc3 amd64 1.0.2-1 [39.3 kB]
Get:15 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main binutils amd64 2.25-5 [3,516 kB]
Get:16 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main cpp amd64 4:4.9.2-2 [17.3 kB]
Get:17 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main cpp-4.8 amd64 4.8.4-1 [4,577 kB]
Get:18 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main cpp-4.9 amd64 4.9.2-10 [5,169 kB]
Get:19 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main gcc-4.9 amd64 4.9.2-10 [5,352 kB]
Get:20 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main make amd64 4.0-8.1 [349 kB]
Get:21 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main fakeroot amd64 1.20.2-1 [84.7 kB]
Get:22 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgcc-4.8-dev amd64 4.8.4-1 [1,689 kB]
Get:23 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main gcc-4.8 amd64 4.8.4-1 [4,787 kB]
Get:24 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.16.7-ckt25-1 [1,023 kB]
Get:25 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libc6-dev amd64 2.19-18+deb8u4 [2,002 kB]
Get:26 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 amd64 3.16.7-ckt25-1 [323 kB]
Get:27 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main linux-headers-amd64 amd64 3.16+63 [5,050 B]
Get:28 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main manpages-dev all 3.74-1 [1,865 kB]
Get:29 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgcc-4.9-dev amd64 4.9.2-10 [2,066 kB]
Get:30 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main gcc amd64 4:4.9.2-2 [5,136 B]
Get:31 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-2 [70.9 kB]
Get:32 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libfakeroot amd64 1.20.2-1 [44.7 kB]
Get:33 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.19-18+deb8u4 [237 kB]
Get:34 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common amd64 3.16.7-ckt25-1 [4,519 kB]
Get:35 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main linux-kbuild-3.16 amd64 3.16.7-ckt20-1 [174 kB]
Get:36 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64 3.16.7-ckt25-1 [451 kB]
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
Fetched 40.3 MB in 18s (2,176 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libasan0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 29817 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libasan0_4.8.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan0:amd64 (4.8.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasan1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libasan1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatomic1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libatomic1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatomic1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcilkrts5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcilkrts5_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcilkrts5:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libisl10:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libisl10_0.12.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisl10:amd64 (0.12.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcloog-isl4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcloog-isl4_0.18.2-1+b2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcloog-isl4:amd64 (0.18.2-1+b2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgomp1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgomp1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgomp1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libitm1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libitm1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libitm1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblsan0_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblsan0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmpfr4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmpfr4_3.1.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpfr4:amd64 (3.1.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libquadmath0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libquadmath0_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libquadmath0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtsan0_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtsan0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libubsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libubsan0_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libubsan0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmpc3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmpc3_1.0.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpc3:amd64 (1.0.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package binutils.
Preparing to unpack .../binutils_2.25-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils (2.25-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp-4.9.
Preparing to unpack .../cpp-4.9_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-4.9 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp.
Preparing to unpack .../cpp_4%3a4.9.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp (4:4.9.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp-4.8.
Preparing to unpack .../cpp-4.8_4.8.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-4.8 (4.8.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-4.9-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgcc-4.9-dev_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-4.9-dev:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-4.9.
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-4.9_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-4.9 (4.9.2-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc.
Preparing to unpack .../gcc_4%3a4.9.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:4.9.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package make.
Preparing to unpack .../make_4.0-8.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking make (4.0-8.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfakeroot_1.20.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../fakeroot_1.20.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.20.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgcc-4.8-dev_4.8.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64 (4.8.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-4.8.
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-4.8_4.8.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-4.8 (4.8.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc-dev-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../libc-dev-bin_2.19-18+deb8u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-libc-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_3.16.7-ckt25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev_2.19-18+deb8u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86_3.16.7-ckt25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common_3.16.7-ckt25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-kbuild-3.16.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-kbuild-3.16_3.16.7-ckt20-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-kbuild-3.16 (3.16.7-ckt20-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64_3.16.7-ckt25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-amd64_3.16+63_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-amd64 (3.16+63) ...
Selecting previously unselected package manpages-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../manpages-dev_3.74-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking manpages-dev (3.74-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up libasan0:amd64 (4.8.4-1) ...
Setting up libasan1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libatomic1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libcilkrts5:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libisl10:amd64 (0.12.2-2) ...
Setting up libcloog-isl4:amd64 (0.18.2-1+b2) ...
Setting up libgomp1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libitm1:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up liblsan0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libmpfr4:amd64 (3.1.2-2) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libtsan0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libubsan0:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up libmpc3:amd64 (1.0.2-1) ...
Setting up binutils (2.25-5) ...
Setting up cpp-4.9 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up cpp (4:4.9.2-2) ...
Setting up cpp-4.8 (4.8.4-1) ...
Setting up libgcc-4.9-dev:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up gcc-4.9 (4.9.2-10) ...
Setting up gcc (4:4.9.2-2) ...
Setting up make (4.0-8.1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20.2-1) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.20.2-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Setting up libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64 (4.8.4-1) ...
Setting up gcc-4.8 (4.8.4-1) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Setting up linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Setting up linux-kbuild-3.16 (3.16.7-ckt20-1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.7-ckt25-1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-4-amd64
Setting up linux-headers-amd64 (3.16+63) ...
Setting up manpages-dev (3.74-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Copy iso file C:\Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
stdin: is not a tty
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.20 - guest version is unknown
stdin: is not a tty
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.20 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Starting the VirtualBox Guest AdditionsInstalling the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
 ...done.
stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/kenne/Documents/GitHub/project
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3`,nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1 vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant`,nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1 vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

stdin: is not a tty
unknown mount option `noatime'
valid options:
  rw         mount read write (default)
  ro         mount read only
  uid       =<arg> default file owner user id
  gid       =<arg> default file owner group id
  ttl       =<arg> time to live for dentry
  iocharset =<arg> i/o charset (default utf8)
  convertcp =<arg> convert share name from given charset to utf8
  dmode     =<arg> mode of all directories
  fmode     =<arg> mode of all regular files
  umask     =<arg> umask of directories and regular files
  dmask     =<arg> umask of directories
  fmask     =<arg> umask of regular files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparantly the fault lies within the vagrant file.
I used the following:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1']
```

Which apparantly does not work with windows 10, so I updated it to:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", :mount_options => ['dmode=777','fmode=777']
```

And now the up is working fine.

Comment: This worked for me. I also installed the vaguest vagrant plugin before this and am not sure if was also necessary. 'vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest'